# CSS Transition - Height Ease

Tags: html, css

I have this navigation menu which is purely driven by CSS. It expands on mouse hover and collapses on mouse out. The feature I wanted is to maintain the menu open until another button is hovered.

Is it possible by simply using CSS or do I need to work with jQuery or JavaScript?

I have modified an expanding vertical Navigation menu and the ease effect is not working when height value in the `CSS` is changed. The contents of each Nav element is different and with a  fixed value the desired result can not be gained.

It is better if it can be done in only `CSS`, here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepuns/w55rZ/).

Comment: It works perfectly in Firefox! Great Job! :)

Comment: Looks good in Chrome too.

Comment: The problem is with the height. if i change the height to auto so that i can include all the menu elements the ease feature is not working. it will just open rapidly and close as i move out my mouse. Is there any way to retain the ease effect and display all menu elements ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My solution is to set the height transition on the `li` element, not the `ul`, this way you don't have to infer a total height.

Here is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/siorge/w55rZ/2/

Edit to show code:

```
/*ul Styles*/
.menu-item ul li {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 0px;

 /*Animation*/
 -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
      -o-transition: height 1s ease;
     -ms-transition: height 1s ease;
         transition: height 1s ease;
}


.menu-item:hover li {
  height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
}
```

Comment: That's great. Lemme try that. BTW is there any way to change the :hover to a click event?

Comment: Yes, but that's only possible with Javascript (or a checkbox hack), not CSS.

Comment: I didn't know this checkbox hack, nice one :)

Comment: Also, here is also a "hack" that would work on your purpose. http://jsfiddle.net/3WWWX/1/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting "height: 0;" set "max-height: 0;" then on :hover set "max-height: 500px;"

http://jsfiddle.net/w55rZ/7/

```
.menu-item ul {      
  /* Remove delay by setting transition delay to -0.25s */
  -webkit-transition: all 1s -0.25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 1s -0.25s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 1s -0.25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 1s -0.25s ease-out;
          transition: all 1s -0.25s ease-out;
  max-height: 0;
}

.menu-item:hover ul {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease ;
   max-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: If i need to keep the menu open till the next link is hovered, whats a possible solution?

Comment: hi, I tried both set max-height and height. The transition effect only works on max-height not height. Could someone tell me why?