# Auto Child Height on Mouse hover on Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making some Custom DropDown lists and this works on mouse hover of css.

```
<div class="CusSelect">
     <p>Select from List</p>
     <ul>
        <li>Football</li>
        <li>Cricket</li>
        <li>Hockey</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my complete JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZX8AK/ with css

Now the problem is when we mouse hover the list it immediately sets **height:auto;** while I want to smoothly set height:auto;

We don't know what it's height is going to be because its items will be added dynamically. I don't care if we can do it with JQuery or CSS. All I want is to set it's height auto smoothly.

To check its animated height, we can set

```
.CusSelect:hover > ul
{
     height:100px;
}
```

but this is the problem, we dont know what its height is going to be, so keeping it to auto is necessary.

Comment: It's running smoothly, do you feel it's not smooth....????

Comment: How can you tell it is running smoothly? it is immediately setting height. there is no animation if height is set to auto

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand the problem....

Comment: it already amazed me but couldn't see any problem....

Comment: @C-link when you mouse over the list, it immediately gets dropped down, but I want it get dropped smoothly. please check the fiddle again

Comment: I'm not understanding, anyway look at [animate method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) which might help you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer I gave there would work for you. If the number of `li` element is going to increase, set the height transition on the `li`, not the `ul`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23291728/3541529

Comment: Thanks. This isn't the trick I was looking for but guess what it gave me another great Idea to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped you :) What's your new idea, if I may ask?

Comment: Thanks. Can't make you fully understand but that helped in making beautifull accordins